# Is there any way to manually initiate an AJAX upload with the Kendo Upload control

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am doing an upload via CORS to Amazon S3 with the Kendo Upload control.  I'm having an issue with the fact that I need to grab a signature from my server, then add it to the 'data' for the event object of 'upload' handler I created.  The problem is, of course, that in the handler I fire off an async request to get the signature, and the upload handler continues on it's merry way without the signature data i need.  The published API has no 'upload()' or something command that I could call when my async request returns.

I saw an ASP-Kendo-S3 example somewhere, but it's not exactly clear from that code, how that signature is being obtained, and of course, I'm not using ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Upload has an `onUpload` event. In Kendo's asp.net example there really isn't anything specific to that framework that wouldn't port to anything else.

They populate the page initially with the profile (base64 encoded JSON).

To get a signature for that base64 encoded json profile they use this method (C#):

```
private static string Sign(string text, string key)
{
    var signer = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signer.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));
}
```

It looks pretty self explanatory to the point where you could port it to another language.